# Key Defined, Value Set, But still defined as null

Tags: php, mysql, json

So the code here:

```
// Check to see if user has admin permissions
if($user->hasPermission('admin')) {
    // Display Admin Backpage Link
    echo "<li><a href='" . Config::get('links/app_root') . "admin/'>Admin</a></li>";
}
```

obviously, when i'm calling the `hasPermission()` method, i'm specifying that i want to check if user has the permission admin.

Here's my `hasPermission` method:

```
// User Has Permission Check
public function hasPermission($key) {
    // Pull from the groups table, where the id (group) equals the assigned group of the user
    // id: 1 for standard users (No permissions/Json stored)
    // id: 2 for Moderators (Json: {"moderator":1}
    // id: 3 for admins (Json: {"admin":1,"moderator":1}
    $groups = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->groups));

    // Check if user is in a group or not
    if($groups->count()) {
        $permissions = json_decode($groups->first()->permissions, true);
        if($permissions[$key] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // user does not have permission
    return false;
}
```

After i call this, i'm getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: admin in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/OOP Login System/core/classes/User.php on line 127

Line 127 is this line:

```
if($permissions[$key] == true) {
```

I'm not understanding why admin is null. My database permissions for admin are set as the following within my MySQL database:

```
{
    "admin": 1,
    "moderator": 1
}
```

Whats really crazy is this was all working JUST fine, and i haven't edited the User class at all since i made it. Now I have the 'moderator' permission as well with the JSON set to:

```
{
    "moderator": 1
}
```

and whenever i call `hasPermission('moderator')` I don't get this error. Like i said before I dont understand what went wrong.

Comment: Consider using `if( !empty($permissions[$key]))` instead, as this will handle the permission not being set at all.

Comment: Looks like that worked, wow i feel like an idiot. However, I still dont understand why it broke in the first place. :/ Seriously...

Comment: What is the value of `$this->data()->groups`? You seem to assume it is 3, but it would be good to check that. Or, if it can be 1 or 2, make sure to not assume the `admin` key exists.

Comment: `$this->data()->groups` is an int value. 1, 2, or 3. read the comments in my code above for more information

Answer (score 0):

Switched line 127 from

```
if($permissions[$key] == true) {
```

to:

```
if(!empty($permissions[$key])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

To help mitigate errors as well, might be good practice to encapsulate in try catch blocks.

```
try {
    $error = 'Always throw this error';
    throw new Exception($error);

    // Code following an exception is not executed.
    echo 'Never executed';

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

and also consider as per the comment using if( !empty($permissions[$key]))